# PhpStorm becomes very slow and takes a lot of resources with Contao CMS project

Tags: phpstorm, contao

When I work in PhpStorm IDE with a Contao 4.9 project, the IDE becomes very slow and uses much more then the normal amount of memory. I already excluded almost every possible folder from being indexed, but it is still super slow.

I searched a bit, but only found [this dedicated inspection profile](https://github.com/leofeyer/phpstorm-inspection-profiles) for Contao CMS.

Is there something I'm missing or a way to identify and fix this memory leaks?

Comment: I suggest you contact JetBrains Support directly with such a performance issues: often they are specific to the user environment (works well for one and does not on another computer) and can have different reasons. `Main Menu | Help | Contact Support...` and attach your logs there: 1) `Help | Collect Logs and Diagnostic Data` 2) https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241235-Reporting-performance-problems

Comment: Please do not use Phpstrom as it's a memory eater and burn your laptop faster and makes so much noise if you use it. I hate it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @LazyOne pointed out, the Intellij-Support is quite helpfull and the right place to go ini this matters.

They checked my logs: (Help > Collect Logs...)

And found a broken symlink, which apparently was corrupting the IDE stubs

```
2021-11-23 16:41:33,690 [13456341] INFO - j.psi.stubs.StubTreeLoaderImpl - Can't load file content for stub building: Not a file: .../system/config/tcpdf.php (type=null)
```

Caches should be cleared after removing/fixing the corrupted file: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/invalidate-caches.html

Comment: The wrong/missing symlink should have been flagged as an error though when you execute `composer install` in the Contao Managed Edition.